# How to make a regex call with a '&' or '?' as first character

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a regex call with the following string:

```
if ((/&timeout=true|?scn=header/i).test(url))
```

... and the statement continues. I am receiving this error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/&timeout=true|?scn=header/`: Nothing to repeat

How do I properly make this statement?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to escape the question mark character as it is a regex operator:

```
if ((/&timeout=true|\?scn=header/i).test(url))
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `?` has a special meaning of *repeat zero or one times*, hence the error. Just escape it:

```
/&timeout=true|\?scn=header/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `/(&timeout=true|\?scn=header)/i`

? is a special character in regex so you need to escape it

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://www.regexr.com/3bqlu

Try this:

`/[&\?]timeout=true|[&\?]scn=header/`

It matches both

```
http://example.com/file.html?scn=header&timeout=true
http://example.com/file.html?timeout=true&scn=header
```

because we don't know which parameter comes first

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

`/\&timeout=true|\/?scn=header/i`

Comment: This will make a forward slash optional. Aka the string `/scn=header` and `scn=header` will be matched. It will not try to match `?scn=header`, which is what you originally wanted.

Comment: @ndn yeah you are right, but It works for what I need at the moment